# Problemas al subir código Arduino UNO chino

Tags: arduino

He comprado un pack de inicio en Arduino por Aliexpress con un clon de Arduino UNO R3.

Aqui la placa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando seguir los tutoriales pero me es imposible subir el ejemplo "Blink", ya que da error. Navegando por internet ya he probado con los errores mas comunes:

He instalado los drivers (CH340), he comprobado que la placa es la correcta (Arduino/Genuino UNO), he confirmado que el puerto tambien es correcto (COM3) e incluso hemos "quemado" el bootloader desde un Arduino Uno original, todo esto sin exito.

El error que me muestra el IDE es el siguiente:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\arduino-1.8.9\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM3
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que pruebes a bajar la velocidad de comunicación, probar desde 9600baudios e ir incrementando.

Comment: una de las cosas que pueden fallar son los drives a mi me pasaba mucho con el arduino mega tengo un par de libreria que te pueden ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dan las opciones iniciales a validar
https://www.picuino.com/es/arduprog/troubleshooting-arduino.html
Entiendo que ya hiciste las primeras sin éxito.
En caso de que tengas algo adicional conectado quítalo de la tarjeta mientras programas.
Igual prueba lo que comentaron de bajar los baudios, o cambia el cable que estas utilizando.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo que te esta diciendo es que a la hora de compilar al ser una copia el programa original no tiene registrado la placa esto me paso a mi al principio que sin querer ponía la placa de Arduino uno en vez de la mega.
Te recomiendo que te compres el Arduino Mega que es una placa base que esta registrada y funciona a la perfección porqué es la que utilice durante muchos años

[image: Esto es donde tendrias que llegar y encontrar tu placa]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es un error de programación; es un error de comunicación, y es frecuente cuando quieres traspasar el código. La única solución ha sido desconectar, reconectar, reintentar. Comprar un modelo distinto no es una solución.

Comment: Yo creo que si porque es lo que me paso a mi al cambiar de placa todo se soluciono

Comment: Una anécdota no es información.